# IDIV in x86 Assembly - Calculating an average

Tags: assembly, x86

I am just trying to calculate an average. Not sure I quite understand IDIV and can't really find anything on it. Here is my current code:

```
;calculate average : sum  / numCount = average

calculateAverage:
mov     edx, 0
mov     eax, sum
mov     ebx, numCount
idiv    ebx
mov     average, eax

mov     edx, OFFSET averageMessage  ; "The average is "
call    writestring

mov     ebx, average
call    writeint
call    crlf
jmp     goodbyeLoop
```

With this current code, it looks like I'm getting a memory address or something as it's just random numbers! Thank you guys for any help.

Comment: Are you sure your `writeint` takes input in `ebx`? Other than that the code looks fine.

Comment: `mov     ebx, average` should be `mov     eax, average`

Comment: You should use `cdq` / `idiv` for signed division.  Setting EDX to 0 only makes sense for unsigned division.  Your result will be bogus if `sum` is negative.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you brotha! I think that might be my issue.

Comment: Without a [mcve] that includes the actual input and output, nobody can tell except you.  What looks like "random numbers" to you is potentially just large positive numbers from effectively truncating your 64-bit signed dividend to 32 bits.